# Linearized map of rivers - what is this called?

Tags: cartography, rivers

I am looking for a "linearized overview" map (as in the figure below) of the Brahmaputra river. I don't know the exact name of this type of map. Do you have any suggestion on what I should look for, and where?

[image]

Comment: This a more geography than GIS, but in pavement management this can be called a "strip map". It's hard to believe a google won't provide an answer.

Comment: Questions relating to geography without a clear GIS component are off-topic in GIS SE.

Comment: Most likely it is a map-scheme of comparative analysis of the lengths and tortuosity of deep-water rivers of the European-Asian region...:-),

Answer (score 1):

Your one liner river map looks like a simplification of complex hydrological flow of water. In power engineering that type of map sometime referred as single-line diagram/SLD. You can even add map after the words.

At present, mapping of electricity transmission and distribution lines is generally described in the form of this type diagram. SLD itself is just a schematic picture of the circuit (three-phase power system) from electricity source (generator) to the final load / user. These diagrams are certainly very helpful for knowing the logic of electrical circuits through its forming components.

One important thing: elements on the diagram do not represent the physical size or location of the electrical equipment as also described in this wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-line_diagram